# Menu with categories and brands :Magento

Tags: magento-1.8, menu

How to create a navigation menu with brand(manufacturer) attribute? 
Reference site is

http://www.demon-tweeks.co.uk.

Please reply guys its mega urgent and i need help .
thanks

Comment: Demanding peoples time is not the best way to receive help. You need an enhanced menu extension, there are plenty to chose from, most are effectively static blocks with the brands being manually added.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your issue?

Comment: Can you please help me to find a solution so i can add category for each brand
i need to make a navigation like brand/category/products
Adidas/clothes/products
clothes/BRANDS/produtcs Any idea regards

Answer (score 3):

Explaining how to create a menu extension might be a bit to elaborate for one post but some pointers.

1) Create a category for each brand so you can use Magento's default top menu. Added benefit are the nice URLS like `domain.com/brands/brandname-x`

2) Create a category that holds all products and make it an anchor category so you have layered navigation. Now you can filter on that category with the normal layered navigation URLS. This would be an url like `domain.com/brands/?brand=22`

There are a couple of extensions out there that offer you more freedom creating a menu like [Tsdesign Menubuilder](http://www.tsdesigns.de/en/tsdesigns-menubuilder.html) or [Mageworld Megamenu](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/mega-menu-by-mageworld.html)